# Rust - writeln! doesn't write to file

Tags: rust, writer

The reader() method works, and the data from the file is loaded, but the writer() does not work, and there is no error, it simply does not write silently. But when I open the file manually (without using the CookieStoreFS structure) and create a BufWriter, everything works fine.

I have following code:

```
use std::{path::PathBuf, env::current_dir, fs::File, error::Error, io::{BufReader, BufWriter}};


//TODO ERROR IF COOKIE FILE NOT EXISTS
pub struct CookieStoreFS{
    path: PathBuf,
}

impl Default for CookieStoreFS {
    fn default() -> Self {
        let mut default_path = current_dir().unwrap();
        default_path.push("cookie.json");
        Self { path: default_path }
    }
}

impl CookieStoreFS{
    pub fn new(path: PathBuf) -> Self{
        Self{
            path
        }
    }

    fn create(&self) -> Result<File, Box<dyn Error>>{
        match File::create(&self.path){
            Ok(f) => Ok(f),
            Err(err) => Err(err.into())
        }
    }

    fn open(&self) -> Result<File, Box<dyn Error>>{
        if !self.path.exists(){
            return self.create()
        }
        return match File::open(&self.path){
            Ok(f) => Ok(f),
            Err(err) => Err(err.into())
        }
    }

    pub fn reader(&self) -> Result<BufReader<File>, Box<dyn Error>>{
        let file = self.open()?;
        Ok(BufReader::new(file))
    }

    pub fn writer(&self) -> Result<BufWriter<File>, Box<dyn Error>>{
        let file = self.open()?;
        Ok(BufWriter::new(file))
    }
}
```

and it doesn't write to the file without any errors:

```
let mut writer = COOKIE_STORE_FS.writer().unwrap();
writeln!(writer, "asdasd");
writeln!(&mut writer, "asdasd");
```

Comment: [It works fine in the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=68f96cd3967148765d72c62aef105cd5). Are you sure the working directory is correct?

Comment: Yes, indeed, it writes to a file. I found a bug - if the file exists, it does not write anything to it, and if the file does not exist, then it creates and writes it. Am I doing something wrong when opening the file?

Comment: "Attempts to open a file in **read-only** mode." https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fs/struct.File.html#method.open

Answer (score 2):

I fixed my problem with following code:

```
File::options().read(true).write(true).open(&self.path)
```

Comment: You should also [call `.flush()` on the `BufWriter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufWriter.html): "It is critical to call `flush` before `BufWriter<W>` is dropped. Though dropping will attempt to flush the contents of the buffer, any errors that happen in the process of dropping will be ignored. Calling `flush` ensures that the buffer is empty and thus dropping will not even attempt file operations." This is the reason you didn't see any error in your first attempt, and it just silently didn't work.